# program with grpc shared libraries,sometimes the process hang forever

Tags: c++, grpc

1. complie grpc shared library;
   `cmake ../.. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/grpc -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=14`
2. write a user.proto file with message and service,then use protoc generate 4 file(user.pb.h,user.pb.cc,user.grpc.pb.h,user.grpc.pb.cc);
3. main function like this:

```
int main()
{
    cout<<getpid()<<endl;
    cout<<"1"<<endl;
    grpc_init();
    cout<<"2"<<endl;
    auto ptr = grpc::InsecureServerCredentials();
    cout<<"3"<<endl;
    ServerBuilder builder;
    builder.AddListeningPort("127.0.0.1:10012", ptr);
    cout<<"4"<<endl;
    //UserServiceImpl user;
    //builder.RegisterService(&user);
    cout<<"5"<<endl;
    auto WebServer = builder.BuildAndStart();
    cout<<"6"<<endl;
    while(1) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

4. cmakelists.txt like this

```
...
file(GLOB TEST_SOURCE ${PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}/main.cpp)
file(GLOB PROTOBUF_SOURCE ${PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}/ProtoBufGen/user.pb.cc ${PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}/ProtoBufGen/user.grpc.pb.cc)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${TEST_SOURCE} ${PROTOBUF_SOURCE})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
    ${GRPC_LIB}
    libdl.so
        libsystemd.so
    liblz4.so
        libpthread.so
    )
```

5. when i run the program,only print "1",then hang forever;
   if i delete the
   `${PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}/ProtoBufGen/user.grpc.pb.cc`
   in cmakelists.txt,then the program can print from 1 to 6,buf if i delete `grpc_init()` in main,it will also just print "1",then hang forever.

i post the question on github,did anyone meet this or know what is the possible reason?
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/32942